# ¿Por qué el "aside" no se me pone a la derecha de los "articles"?

Tags: html, css

***HTML***

```
<head>
     <meta charset="utf-8"/>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Estilos.css"/>
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximun-scalw=1.0,minimun-scale=1.0">/>
     <title>Test</title>

</head>

<body>

    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/34/Regensburg_Uferpanorama_08_2006.jpg/770px-Regensburg_Uferpanorama_08_2006.jpg"/>
    <div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li>Principal</li>
            <li>Galeria</li>
            <li>Contacto</li>
            <li>Actividades</li>


        </ul>
    </div> 
    <article id="articulo1">
    <h1 style="color:#FFFFF">Principal</h1>
        <p>
    Muy lejos, más allá de las montañas de palabras, alejados de los países de las vocales y las consonantes, viven los textos simulados. Viven aislados en casas de letras, en la costa de la semántica, un gran océano de lenguas. Un riachuelo llamado Pons fluye por su pueblo y los abastece con las normas necesarias. Hablamos de un país paraisomático en el que a uno le caen pedazos de frases asadas en la boca. Ni siquiera los todopoderosos signos de puntuación dominan a los textos simulados; una vida, se puede decir, poco     
    </p>






    </article>
    <article>
    <h2>Segundo Principal</h2>
    uno le caen pedazos de frases asadas en la boca. Ni siquiera los todopoderosos signos de puntuación dominan a los textos simulados; una vida, se puede decir, poco. Y, viéndole don Quijote de aquella manera, con 






    </article>

    <aside>
        <h id="asidetitle"><u>Latest news</u></h>

        <p>Y, viéndole don Quijote de aquella manera, con muestras de tanta tristeza, le dijo: Sábete, Sancho, que no es un hombre más que otro si no hace más que otro. Todas estas borrascas que nos suceden son señales de que presto ha de serenar el tiempo y han de sucedernos bien las cosas; porque no es posible que el mal ni el bien sean</p>
        <cite>El Quijote,Cervantes.</cite>



    </aside>
</body>
```

***CSS***

```
ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: black
    }
li{
    color: aliceblue;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-left:50px;
    font-family: sans-serif;



}
html{


    background-color: darkred
}
#asidetitle{


    color: white;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size:20px; 

}
aside{


    float:right;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: 70%;
    padding: 1%;



}
article{
    float: left;
    color: white;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-right: 30%





}
```

Comment: Explica tu problema, lo que has intentado, que es lo que te falla con mas exactitud, si pones un bloque de texto nadie va a saber que es lo que quieres realmente.

Comment: o sea lo que quiiero es poner un texto paralelamente a otro,(como comunmente van los asides) y el problema creo que radica en que el aside ocupa toda la pagina

Answer (score 1):

Que sea `aside` no significa que se va a poner a la derecha solo... tienes que decirle a todo que es lo que va a la izquierda y que es lo que va a la derecha! aquí un ejemplo

```
<style>
    .page{
        display: table;
        width: 100%
    }
    .container {
        float: right;
        width: 60%
    }
    aside{
        float: left;
        width: 40%
    }
</style>

<div class="page">
    <section class="container">
        <article>
            Articulo 1
        </article>
        <article>
            Articulo 2
        </article>
    </section>
    <aside>
        <h4>Titulo</h4>
    </aside>
</div>
```